# Ubuntu C Programming Expected Float but argument is of type double *

Tags: c, ubuntu

I am trying to write a program that calculates areas and volumes and the average of the given numbers.I succesfully did these but when i try to calculate the standard deviation I get an error which i dont know how to solve and I couldn`t even understand what was the problem So as my last resort I request you guys help.Thanks Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int squaresarea(int edge)
{   
    int area = edge * edge;
    printf ("Area of the square : %d\n",area);

    return 0;
}
int rectanglesarea(int edge1,int edge2)
{
    int rectanglesarea = edge1 * edge2;
    printf ("Area of the rectangle : %d\n",rectanglesarea);
}
float spheresvolume(int radius)
{
    float spheresvolume = (4.0/3)*M_PI*radius*radius*radius;
    printf("Volume of the sphere: %f\n",spheresvolume);
}
float cylindersvolume(float radius1,float height)
{
    float cylindersvolume = M_PI*radius1*radius1*height;
    printf("Volume of the cylinder %f\n",cylindersvolume);
}
double average(float edge,float edge1,float edge2,float radius,float radius1,float height)
{
    double average = (edge + edge1 + edge2 + radius + radius1 + height)/6;
    printf("Average of the values entered: %f\n",average);
}
double standarddeviation(int edge,float average)
{

    double standarddeviation = (edge - average);
}
int main (int edge,int edge1,int edge2,int radius,int radius1,int height)
{
    printf("Enter the length of your square`s edge: ");
    scanf("%d",&edge);
    squaresarea(edge);
    printf("Enter the lengths of your rectangles edges:");
    scanf("%d %d",&edge1,&edge2);
    rectanglesarea(edge1,edge2);
    printf("Enter radius of your sphere: ");
    scanf("%d",&radius);
    spheresvolume(radius);
    printf("Enter radius and height of your cylinder: ");
    scanf("%d %d",&radius1,&height);
    cylindersvolume(radius1,height);
    average(edge,edge1,edge2,radius,radius1,height);
    standarddeviation(edge,average);
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the error i get:

[image: Error message screenshot]

Comment: The error is because names have to be unique. You have a function and a variable named `standarddeviation`. Also you have much more problems in your code: http://ideone.com/I7nSJJ

Comment: Please post your error messages as text instead. Also there are too many errors in your code. Try compiling it with `-Wall`.

Comment: so i have to change the one in the function standarddeviation to something else?

Comment: i get rid of most of the problems http://ideone.com/F83t6N but what i dont understand is it says M_PI undeclared but i already include math.h so should it say this?

Answer (score 0):

standarddeviation() requires a float value as the second argument, but you passed the name of the function - avearge(). If you want to pass the return value of average(), you should use standarddeviation() like this,

```
standarddeviation(edge, average(edge,edge1,edge2,radius,radius1,height));
```